# Как нужно хранить строку подключения?

Tags: c#, winforms

Я новичок в c# и на данный момент в моём коде строка подключения прописана так :

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"тут строка");
```

По совету людей на этом сайте я хочу переписать все блоки где требуется подключение на вот так :

```
 using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"строка подключения"))
    {
        cn.Open();
        //остальной код
    }
```

Меня беспокоит несколько вопросов :

1. Увеличится количество символов в коде, так как, сейчас я использую `cn.Open()` и `cn.Close()`, это плохо?
2. Строку подключения я планирую зашить в public string, для использования ее во всей ПО, это опасно или лучше в каждом `using` прописывать строку подключения заново?
3. Действительно ли лучше переписать весь код согласно совета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Относительно ваших вопросов:

1. Количество символов в коде увеличится, но это **вообще** не проблема. Даже не думайте про неё. Close для using - не обязательно.
2. Безопасно. Но лучше по совету @Ruslan_K засунуть её в конфиг и использовать так. При этом, у вас скорее всего появится подобный метод:

   ```
   public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
   {
       var c new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
       c.Open();
       return c;
   }
   ```

Соответственно, код использования будет:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = Helper.GetConnection())
{
    // ваш код работы с базой
}
```

3. Да. Обязательно. Использование *Disposable* обектов должно быть в `using`. Когда вы выходите из блока using, C# вызывает метод `Dispose` у `ConnectionString` что эквивалентно `Close`. Если вы будете всегда самостоятельно вызывать метод `Close`, то рано или поздно вы его забудете и будет утечка строк соединения, что может привести к ошибкам при высокой нагрузке, когда Garbage Collector не успеет закрыть за вас соединение с базой данных. Даже если вы считаете, что вы не будете забывать это делать, то любой эксепшен во время работы с базой данных (например, не смогли преобразовать строку в число, приведёт к висящей коннекции.

Comment: Во первых, спасибо за развернутый ответ. `Disposable` == `Dispose()` или это какой то метод, который тоже надо вызывать дополнительно?

Comment: Disposable - это *паттерн*, т.е. объекты, которым надо явно освобождать ресурсы. В реальности, они наследуют интерфейс `IDisposable` с методом `Dispose`. если этот объект внутри `using` то `Dispose` вызывается автоматически.

Comment: Так файл конфигурации любой пользователь откроет в текстовом редакторе и увидит данные для подключения к серверу БД

Answer (score 1):

строку подключения лучше хранить в файле конфигурации

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DB" connectionString="строка подключения"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Получить доступ к строке можно так:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString
```

Используя конструкцию `using` вам не нужно будет каждый раз вызывать метод `cn.Close()`

Comment: Так все таки, лучше `using` или оставить как есть?